# Load javascript and CSS in Google App engine, how can I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-app-engine

I try to upload my html file with Javascript and css by Google App Engine.
and local upload show to clearly work well.
but, after I deploy to server, server can't read my javascript and CSS
How can I solve this..? Please Help me...

[Deploy project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqwfH.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by *can't read*? Check the resource tab in chrome dev tools to see what status codes the server returns.

Comment: Please clarify what code on the client side, and what code on the server side, are you using to "upload" and try to "read" JS and CSS -- and where is the server-side code trying to stash the "uploaded" contents (in the datastore, presumably?). The question as it stands is FAR too vague for us to be able to help you until you add a LOT of specific clarification!